# Prometheus for k8s to forward to master prometheus server

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, monitoring

I have a master Prometheus (single one installed to the VM).
It monitors multiple VM instances.
Right now I need to install full prometheus monitoring over my GKE cluster to be able to monitor GKE system metrics and the pods and have all the metrics in my master Prometheus.
Please advice the best practices or your experience.

Comment: If you unsure where to begin, the [ptometheus operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator) might be a nice choice.

Comment: This guide might help you [Using Promotheus](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/prometheus#before_you_begin) on GKE. For Pomotheus setup and cloud monitoring you may refer on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/monitoring-apps-running-on-multiple-gke-clusters-using-prometheus-and-stackdriver?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

So the best and fastest way to put a flag --enable-feature=remote-write-receiver and use remote-write features.